# Can i use ajax inside JavaScript? I have used it but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have used AJAX inside JavaScript where I want to send a few parameters and set the button value from lock to unlock when a certain condition is true. But it doesn't work, I mean it doesn't go to AJAX.

Here is my code, which is being called with a button onclick function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("lockId");
        var orderid = document.getElementById("order_no");
        if (elem.value == "Lock") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {Lock_Id: 1, Order_No: orderid},
                url: '@Url.Action("LockClick","Orders")',
                success: function (result) {
                    elem.value = "Unlock";
                }
            });
        } else if (elem.value == "Unlock") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {Lock_Id: 0, Order_No: orderid},
                url: '@Url.Action("LockClick","Orders")',
                success: function (result) {
                    elem.value = "Lock";
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Help will highly be appreciated, I might be making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Url.Action("LockClick","Orders") looks suspicious, it looks like you ripped it out of a dynamic web solution, that isn't JavaScript. What are the actual URLs you need to use?

Comment: have you included jquery ?

Comment: The point of JQuery is to use it within javascript - it's a javascript framework. I've never seen something like @Url.Action() though.

Comment: Weird title. The J in AJAX stands for Javascript, you know?

Comment: @JeffWatkins: i have use the same ajax syntax before and it worked, but after i used it here with button change funtion it doesnt trigger,

Comment: @RahulNaik  I have put alert inside the change function but only ajax doenst work, Shouldnt i be using ajax inside it??

Comment: @Hamadkhan can you please check inside the Network tab of the chrome Developer tool whether request is sent or not ?
Also any javascript error on chrome console??

Comment: @RahulNaik: THanks for your reply, I have checked it, console doesnt show any error, and second thing, when i click on lock button, its value does change to unlock but when the page is refreshed it again change to Lock, is there anything where i can change the button value permanently ?  this is also a big headache for me? it might be easy bt m finding it difficult, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert native javascript data object to JSON. Just like that:

```
data:JSON.stringify({Lock_Id: 1, Order_No: parseInt(orderid)})
```

Also you need to specify content type of your AJAX request:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Also you have following mistake in js code:

```
var orderid = document.getElementById("order_no")
```

now in orderid you have **object**, not value of element. I assume on orderid you just have simple html input field. In this case you need replace your string by following:

```
var orderid = document.getElementById("order_no").value;
```

Also you need to parse **orderid** to int, because it came from **.value** as **string** and you **expect integer** in your controller's method.

Thank you for posting controller's code. There are several tiny mistakes on it. Please use following string to fix:

```
public ActionResult LockClick(int Lock_Id, int Order_No, int cust_acctNo = 0, int store_id = 0)
```

1. Please be sure you have named method parameters exactly as they named in client side javascript - it will makes your code more strict and visual.
2. I have added default value for **cust_acctNo** parameter because you never pass it's value from client side to server side - in your example you have only pass two parameters instead of three.

Now it should work.

Please find fixed javascript code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {

        var elem = document.getElementById("lockId");
        var orderid = document.getElementById("order_no").value;
        if (elem.value == "Lock") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Lock_Id: 1, Order_No: parseInt(orderid) }),
                url: '@Url.Action("LockClick","Index")',
                success: function (result) {
                    elem.value = "Unlock";
                }
            });
        } else if (elem.value == "Unlock") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Lock_Id: 0, Order_No: parseInt(orderid) }),
                url: '@Url.Action("LockClick", "Index")',
                success: function (result) {
                    elem.value = "Lock";
                }
            });
        }

        return false;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Dear @Anton Norko It doesnt give any error, I have put alert inside the change function which works, but only ajax doesnt work, It doesnt pass the parameters to the required action which i have provided in url

Comment: This is the Action in controller:

 public ActionResult LockClick(int Lock_Id, int order_No, int cust_acctNo, int store_id=0)
        {
            _Orders Orders_ = new _Orders();

          

       

            Orders_.UnLock_Lock_Trade_Order(1, order_No);

            return RedirectToAction(null, new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Orders", action = "Edit", order_No = order_No, cust_acctNo = cust_acctNo, store_id = 8 }));
    
        }

Comment: Thank you very much sir, It worked, Really Appreciated.

But sir i have little problem, When i click on Lock button it initially changes to Unlock as i per my code but when the page refreshes it again change to Lock, I want the value of button to be permantly changed after i click on it, Hope you got my question.

Comment: @Hamadkhan - you need to store Lock\Unlock status somewhere. And then on your general Action method you need just read that status and then render your button according that status. Lock\Unlock status can be passed to view via specific field in model, or TempData["LockedStatus"] = isLocked;    And then in view something like that: <button id="myButton">@(TempData["LockedStatus"] == null || (bool)TempData["LockedStatus"] == false ? "Lock" : "Unlock")</button>

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the `url` parameter of the ajax request:

`url: '@Url.Action("LockClick","Orders")',`

If you look in the dev tools of the browser, at the network tab, what is the actual URL that is being requested?

Is the script embedded in some kind of template? Does the template get compiled at any point and that string converted into an actual URL?

## edit

What if you put an alert inside each branch of the if statement, then what happens? What does `elem.value` equal? It could be a problem with the [type conversion of the loose equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) (`==`), depending on what type `elem.value` is.

Comment: I have put the alert inside the change function which works perfectly, it means jquery works, but the problem is with ajax, it is not being triggered

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the orderId line is missing `.value` in the end.  Should be:

```
var orderid = document.getElementById("order_no").value;
```

Comment: Thanks, @anton-norko. [Checked](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/0ru5LfkL/). You're right. Wrong answer removed.